# TypeScript. Assign JSX element to variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a very simple function that returns an input and its value. The problem is that I don't know how to assign the JSX element to a variable. When using usual React, everything is fine, but with TypeScript, i have an error. Here is the function itself:

```
export const useInput = () => {
    const [val, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

    const inputValueHandler = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const currentTarget = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        setInputValue(currentTarget.value);
    };
      
     const input: JSX.Element = <input value={val} onChange={inputValueHandler}/>;
    
    return [val, input];
  }
```

error appears here

```
     const input: JSX.Element = <input value={val} onChange={inputValueHandler}/>;
```

an error

```
"input" refers to a value, but is used as a type here. Did you mean "typeof input"?ts(2749)
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this error! Would it be possible if you could make a playground perhaps? [typescriptlang.org/playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdWAHpLHLhAHarwCuqWAJKcwveAF44ACgCUALjgBtHlGCcA5gBo4AKQDKADQB0AUQA2WEFk4wAunHEA+OAG86cD+y48lAN2Rm2gIwwqIwAGoBvFj2kth4MEb8WHowyDBYUgBEWTL07p4c3PBqYZFm0QASyJwAJhZQDtJYCvH4RgBi0CAmvtYwADyVACoAsgAyoWLmlv2OMg7Obp4rXsXsvFCUNsPIUOpYEnBYRmn7hyjoIxNTMDNWNvSrnsG35dFSuJvbMLvnif4Klg8gUPABfJ6eUFrHylMQKfTGe79JoDOHwQHRcQuQFguBcADCAAsagdsej3lhqnUGmCAPSOSEeaGUGCbTh+ALadG2ehguhAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not telling TypeScript that that code uses JSX, so it thinks the `<input ...` is the beginning of a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (the angle bracket kind, not the `as` kind). ([Playground link to the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdWAHpLHLhAHarwCuqWAJKcwveAF44ACgCUALjgBtHlGCcA5gBo4AKQDKADQB0AUQA2WEFk4wAunHEA%20OAG86cD%20y48lAN2Rm2gIwwqIwAGoBvFj2kth4MEb8WHowyDBYUgBEWTL07p4c3PBqYZFm0QASyJwAJhZQDtJYCvH4RgBi0CAmvtYwADyVACoAsgAyoWLmlv2OMg7Obp4rXsXsvFCUNsPIUOpYEnBYRmn7hyjoIxNTMDNWNvSrnsG35dFSuJvbMLvnif4Klg8gUPABfJ6eUFrHylMQKfTGe79JoDOHwQHRcQuQFguBcADCAAsagdsej3lhqnUGmCAPSOSEeaGUGCbTh%20ALadG2ehguhAA) with the playground configured not to allow JSX.)

If you tell TypeScript that that code is JSX (for instance, by putting it in a `.tsx` file), it works just fine. ([Playground example showing no error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdWAHpLHLhAHarwCuqWAJKcwveAF44ACgCUALjgBtHlGCcA5gBo4AKQDKADQB0AUQA2WEFk4wAunHEA%20OAG86cD%20y48lAN2Rm2gIwwqIwAGoBvFj2kth4MEb8WHowyDBYUgBEWTL07p4c3PBqYZFm0QASyJwAJhZQDtJYCvH4RgBi0CAmvtYwADyVACoAsgAyoWLmlv2OMg7Obp4rXsXsvFCUNsPIUOpYEnBYRmn7hyjoIxNTMDNWNvSrnsG35dFSuJvbMLvnif4Klg8gUPABfJ6eUFrHylMQKfTGe79JoDOHwQHRcQuQFguBcADCAAsagdsej3lhqnUGmCAPSOSEeaGUGCbTh%20ALadG2ehguhAA) when the playground is set to support JSX.)